# UDP server is working well but it accepts the client request only once

Tags: java, android, server

I have made a UDP server. It is working well but the problem is, It only accepts the client request once and gives response but on sending the 2nd request it does not replies to the client and also doesnot receives the message.

Here is my code....... I am unable to troubleshoot this

```
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(SERVERPORT,
                        serverAddr);
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                updatetrack("Server: Receiving\n");
                socket.receive(packet);
                updatetrack("Server: Message received: '"
                        + new String(packet.getData()) + "'\n");
                updatetrack("Server: Succeed!\n");
                updatetrack("I want to send the data to you .......");
                byte[] sbuff;
                sbuff = ("opSERVERSTARTED").getBytes();
                socket.send(new DatagramPacket(sbuff, sbuff.length, packet
                        .getAddress(), packet.getPort()));
```

Answer (score 0):

`socket.receive(packet);` I think this code must be in a while loop, so it can accept more than one client. Something like this:

`InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(SERVERPORT,
                        serverAddr);
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                while (someCondition) {
                updatetrack("Server: Receiving\n");
                socket.receive(packet);
                updatetrack("Server: Message received: '"
                        + new String(packet.getData()) + "'\n");
                updatetrack("Server: Succeed!\n");
                updatetrack("I want to send the data to you .......");
                byte[] sbuff;
                sbuff = ("opSERVERSTARTED").getBytes();
                socket.send(new DatagramPacket(sbuff, sbuff.length, packet
                        .getAddress(), packet.getPort()));
                }`

I am not sure about the end of the curly brackets, I am not familiar with UDP server. You can move it to where the repeating code ends. Hope this helps!

Comment: i think it may be true but what about to send the packet to the received client. How he will do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code implies that you only want to receive one packet. 
If you want to receive more packets, you have to do that in a loop and handle the runtime of the loop by a defined stop criteria.

Comment: Please can u provide the little instance of code !!

Comment: @koolmaan You need an example of a loop?

Comment: If u can provide it will be easy to me to figure it out as fast as required